# Using Stored Procedure Debit Credit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to Do Debit and Credit using Stored procedures and to update the account balances.

My SQL Code looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DebitCr

@AccountNumber1 varchar(50) = null,
@AccountNumber2 varchar(50) = null,
@balance money = null, 
@amount money = null

AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE account_Balances SET @balance = @balance - @amount WHERE @AccountNumber1 = @AccountNumber1
UPDATE account_Balances SET @balance = @balance + @amount WHERE @AccountNumber2 = @AccountNumber2

END
GO
```

Now to Run the stored Procedure i do this :

```
EXEC DebitCr
@AccountNumber1 = '0023889098',
@AccountNumber2 = '0023889133',
@balance = 165000,
@amount = 15000
```

For some Reason it does not Update the Account Balances Effectively,What exactly did I get wrongly?

Comment: You need `COALEACE(@balance, 0), COALESCE(@amount, 0)` before doing anythings.

Comment: Stop and think first. There is no - ZERO - reason for your procedure to accept any parameter value that is null. To the contrary, your procedure should reject null values either directly or via constraints on the affected table. Do not encourage lazy coding and do not hide mistakes from procedure users that do not provide correct information.

Comment: @SMor, Actually i started to Learn Stored Procedures today. so Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are passing the *balance* into the stored procedure.  It is stored in the table.  I think the amount is the only thing needed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DebitCr (
    @AccountNumber1 varchar(50) = null,
    @AccountNumber2 varchar(50) = null,
    @amount money = null

) AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE account_Balances
        SET balance = COALESCE(balance, 0) - COALESCE(@amount, 0)
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber1;

    UPDATE account_Balances
        SET balance = COALESCE(balance, 0) + COALESCE(@amount, 0)
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber2;
END;
GO
```

That said, you probably want to think about how to make the procedure "safe".  Here are some ideas:

- Either do the updates in a single statement or wrap them in a transaction, so they take effect "at the same time".
- Check that *both* accounts are valid *before* changing any values.
- Check that the first account has a large enough `balance` before changing any values.

Other checks might be needed as well, depending on the actual business requirements.

Comment: I think in where condition  as  WHERE '@AccountNumber1' = @AccountNumber1'; left side should be AccountNumber1 not the '@AccountNumber1'.

Comment: Does not Subtract do the Debit and Credit. All is still the same

Comment: @SurajKumar . . . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` values cause the problems :

```
UPDATE account_Balances 
       SET balance = COALESCE(@balance, 0) - COALESCE(@amount, 0)
WHERE AccountNumber1 = @AccountNumber1

UPDATE account_Balances 
       SET balance = COALESCE(@balance, 0) + COALESCE(@amount, 0) 
WHERE AccountNumber2 = @AccountNumber2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks for the heads up. I followed what @Suraj Kumar , and Gordon Linoff said and its Deducting fine now. Thanks Everyone

SQL Source code for Debit Credit is given thus :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DebitCr (
    @AccountNumber1 varchar(50) = null,
    @AccountNumber2 varchar(50) = null,
    @amount money = null

) AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE account_Balances
        SET balance = COALESCE(balance, 0) - COALESCE(@amount, 0)
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber1;

    UPDATE account_Balances
        SET balance = COALESCE(balance, 0) + COALESCE(@amount, 0)
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber2;
END;
GO
```

Now i do something like this :

```
EXEC DebitCr
@AccountNumber1 = '0023889098',
@AccountNumber2 = '0023889133',
@amount = 15000
```

Works Fine, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the parameter to column name as shown below in update statement.

```
UPDATE account_Balances SET balance = ISNULL(@balance, 0) - ISNULL(@amount,0) WHERE AccountNumber1 = @AccountNumber1
UPDATE account_Balances SET balance = ISNULL(@balance, 0) + ISNULL(@amount,0) WHERE AccountNumber2 = @AccountNumber2
```

To handle `null` value you can use `ISNULL`.